# GUI over SSH problem

Tags: ssh, gui

I'm trying to run Midori on my Raspberry Pi over SSH and I would like it to appear on the screen of my PC. (The PC runs Xubuntu.) I tried to follow [instructions like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine), but I still can't see the browser appearing on my screen.

- I do use `ssh -X`
- `X11Forwarding yes` is set on the Raspberry
- `xauth` is installed on the Raspberry
- I even tried to set `X11UseLocalhost no` on the device

And then if I run `DISPLAY=:0 midori` I get debug messages like

```
(midori:11871): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-bar-popup-delay after class was initialised

(midori:11871): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-can-change-accels after class was initialised

(midori:11871): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popup-delay after class was initialised

(midori:11871): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popdown-delay after class was initialised

(midori:11871): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-label-select-on-focus after class was initialised

(midori:11871): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-images after class was initialised

(midori:11871): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-button-images after class was initialised

(midori:11871): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-scrolled-window-placement after class was initialised

(midori:11871): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-entry-select-on-focus after class was initialised

(midori:11871): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-entry-password-hint-timeout after class was initialised
```

Which I guess is OK, but then nothing else happens.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use Upper-case X not a lower case x

> ssh -X

to enable X11 tunneling over SSH.

Also on host you are connecting from do:

```
export DISPLAY=<ip of your host from where you ssh from>:0

xhost +
```

to allow incoming X11 connection from any host

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `xhost` thing. (The -x was just a typo here, I used -X in the terminal.) However I'm not any closer, I still don't see the GUI on the PC.

Comment: @ytg I amended my answer. make sure to export the display as well. SSH -X will do it for you also but I added JIC.

Comment: apparently something needs to listen on the port 6000. what should that be?

Comment: meanwhile I got aware of question like this http://askubuntu.com/questions/34657/how-to-make-x-org-listen-to-remote-connections-on-port-6000 but I don't seem to have `gdm` on my PC

Comment: @ytg Here are my [results](http://pastebin.com/39WQfAkg). After I hit enter after lxterminal command, I get a lxterminal. Laptop is Linux laptop (xserver already running). Host berry is raspberry pi.

Comment: strange. I tried again and now everything works fine. thanks for your efforts helping me.

Comment: Prefer `ssh -Y` to `ssh -X`.